# Average response time from log files

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm new to Elastic and Kibana, I'm working on log files that contains information about some operations on differents levels, I have a field timestamp that represent time when each operation has occured on each level.

I want to calculate the average time spent on each level to visualize it on Kibana, the problem is I did not find something in the documentation or I didn't chose the correct keyword.

As a reminder I want to calculate the time Average processing time for each step of the operation so I can visualize it on Kibana.

This is an exemple of my logs.

{“log_level”:“INFO”,“timestamp”:“2021-12-22T11:49:06.124890Z”,“event_type”:“step1”,“mid”:“96712abc”}{“log_level”:“INFO”,“timestamp”:“2021-12-22T11:49:07.706699Z”,“event_type”:“step2”,“mid”:“96712abc”}
{“log_level”:“INFO”,“timestamp”:“2021-12-22T11:49:08.124890Z”,“event_type”:“step3”,“mid”:“96712abc”}

Comment: can you share your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want the time that the operation "96712abc" spend in the 3 steps of the process "step1,"step2","step3".

Comment: but I don't see the time_spend value in your JSON document? can you tell me what would be the value in case of your sample docus

Comment: Do I need to create this field ? If yes how can I retrieve the time spend from the timestamp ?

Comment: you need to have start and end_timestamp, in order to properly calculate time spend for each step

Comment: Thanks Amit,each step starts at a time defined in timestamp and ends at the beginning of the next step. for exemple step 1 start at 2021-12-22T11:49:06.124890Z and ends at the begining of step 2 which is 2021-12-22T11:49:07.706699Z